# Check if I have clicked on a datagridview row

Tags: .net, vb.net, datagridview

How to check if I have clicked a data in data grid view?
[image]
I have tried `dgv_click`, `_mouseClick`, `_cellcontentClicked`

```
btnEdit.Enabled = true
btnDelete.Enabled = true
```

nothing happens.
I want them to be enabled if the user clicks on either data row.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to create a handler for `.CellClick` event

```
    Private Sub dgv_CellClick(sender AS Object, e As DataGridViewCellEventArgs) Handles dgv.CellClick
        'you can get cell's rowindex and columnindex where was clicked
        If e.RowIndex >= 0 AndAlso e.ColumnIndex >= 0 Then

            'here put your code based on the clicked cell

        End If
    End Sub
```